# Getting the name of generic parameter types

Tags: c#, generics

I have a special Utility class I'm doing some really insane stuff with but one of things of thing I need it to do is get the name of the inner most generic parameter type name.

Allow me to Ellaborate ...

```
public class Magicutil<T>
{
     public string GetNameOfInnerT()
     {
         //TODO
     }
}
```

Now lets assume in this case T is `ISomething<Foo>`
I want to return "Foo".

Any Ideas?

Comment: hmm ... where does the "Foo" come from?

Comment: Replace `//TODO` with `return "Foo"` (or explain your question more carefully)

Comment: `I'm doing some really insane stuff` - if it's insane, why are you doing it?

Comment: Oops sorry guys ... hadn't realised it chopped out the important bit !!!

Comment: @DanPantry My bad ... sorry the question didn't make sense else lol

Comment: it's insane in that i'm thinking a little outside of the box in how web applications and their dependencies are stuck together all will become clear later when i blog about this ... plan to get some community feedback on it.

Comment: What if `T` is `KeyValuePair<string, object>`?

Comment: it never is ... theres a constraint i left out in the code sample above that says T must of type ISomething

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure `T` is generic and has only one generic argument you can directly use `return` part of below code. Otherwise you need to check if `typeof(T).IsGenericType` and may be count of generic arguments.

```
public string GetNameOfInnerT()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (type.IsGenericType) {
        // TODO: what if more than one generic arguments???
        return type.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name;
    }
    // TODO: return null, empty string or throw exception
}
```

Comment: Im not certain but this method is going to handle both a Generic T and a non Generic T ... just testing this now :)

Comment: Your question asks that you want to find `K` in `MagicUtils<T<K>>`... what behaviour would you expect if you didn't have `T<K>` but `T`?

Comment: im testing if T is generic, if it this question is how to get T if it isn't i already have my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a loop:

```
public class Magicutil<T>
{
    public string GetNameOfInnerT()
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        if (t.IsGenericType)
        {
            Type[] tArr;;
            while ((tArr = t.GetGenericArguments()).Length > 0)
                t = tArr[0];
        }
        return t.Name;
    }
}
```

Now this handles also something weird as `Magicutil<ISomething<ISomething<Foo>>>`.

Comment: Funky ... i like this answer but our internal coding standards mean that this particular block of code will never see this type for T ... +1 though :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a precise match to your requirements but this one gives you the C# name of a type, such as `Magicutil<ISomething<ISomething<Foo>>>`

```
    public static string GetClassName(Type cls)
    {
        if (cls.IsGenericType)
        {
            var param = string.Join(",", cls.GetGenericArguments().Select(v => GetClassName(v)).ToArray());
            return cls.Name.Split('`')[0] + "<" + param + ">";
        }
        else
        {
            return cls.Name;
        }
    }
```